# jQuery get a access to element at same level

Tags: jquery

I have

```
<ul id="notifications">
   <li onclick="toggleArrived('{{Aircraft}}',this)"><div class="top notoff"><img src="../lib/img/arrived.png" /></div><div class="bottom notoff">Arrived</div></li>
   <li onclick="toggleBoard('{{Aircraft}}',this)"><div class="top notoff"><img src="../lib/img/board.png" /></div><div class="bottom notoff">Ok to Board</div></li>
   <li onclick=""><div class="top notoff"><img src="../lib/img/done.png" /></div><div class="bottom notoff">Done</div></li>
</ul>
```

now onclick on first "li", I want to change last "li" too.

```
function toggleArrived(ac,obj) {
        for (var i=0;i<data.Aircrafts.length;i++) {
            if (data.Aircrafts[i].Aircraft==ac) {
                if (obj.childNodes[0].className=="top notoff") {
                    data.Aircrafts[i].Aircraft.Arrived="YES";
                    obj.childNodes[0].className="top noton";
                    obj.childNodes[1].className="bottom noton";

                ??? if ($("#notifications li:last-child.childNodes[0]").className =="top notoff") {
                        $("#notifications li:last-child.childNodes[0]").className = "top noton";
                        $("#notifications li:last-child.childNodes[1]").className = "bottom noton";
                    }
                } else {
                    data.Aircrafts[i].Aircraft.Arrived="NO";
                    obj.childNodes[0].className="top notoff";
                    obj.childNodes[1].className="bottom notoff";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I do that?

Comment: It's a existing code, I am trying to use jQuery. I AM NEW to jquery.

Comment: What's `data.Aircrafts`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your function:

```
var lis = obj.parent().children('li');  // Will give you all the lis
```

Or you can use:

```
var lis = obj.siblings().addBack();     // Will give you all the lis
```

And then:

```
lis.filter(':nth-child(x)');            // Will give you li # x
```

Also:

```
lis.filter(':last-child');              // Will give you the last li
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am trying it.

Comment: Can I do filter(':last-child').childNodes[0] to reach the first div in that ?

Comment: Yes, or filter(':last-child').children('div:first');